# How to convert phonetic phone number to numeric phone number?

Tags: java, string, switch-statement

```
public class Driver
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        String phoneNumber;

        System.out.print("Enter a phonetic phone number: ");
        phoneNumber = input.nextLine();

        int i = 0;
        while (i != phoneNumber.length())
        {
            char c = phoneNumber.charAt(i);
            i++;
            if (Character.isDigit(c) == true)
            {
                phoneNumber = String.valueOf(c);
            }
            else if (Character.isLetter(c) == true)
            {
                decode(c);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Improper input");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Numeric version of phone number: " + phoneNumber);
    }

    private static String decode(char c)
    {
        switch (c)
        {
            case 'A':
            case 'B':
            case 'C':
                return "2";
            case 'D':
            case 'E':
            case 'F':
                return "3";
            case 'G':
            case 'H':
            case 'I':
                return "4";
            case 'J':
            case 'K':
            case 'L':
                return "5";
            case 'M':
            case 'N':
            case 'O':
                return "6";
            case 'P':
            case 'Q':
            case 'R':
            case 'S':
                return "7";
            case 'T':
            case 'U':
            case 'V':
                return "8";
            case 'W':
            case 'X':
            case 'Y':
            case 'Z':
                return "9";
        }
        return " ";

    }

}
```

Right now my output is only showing the numeric value for the first digit. I'm not exactly sure what I need to do to display the whole string once it is converted from phonetic to numeric. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are modifying the phonenumber in the loop which is in fact dependent on the phonenumber you need to use a string global for the while loop for the changed number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are *not changing your phone number actually*, you can declare other variable to add changed characters which should be declared outside the loop.

```
    String changedNumber="";//declare outside loop
    //...
    if (Character.isDigit(c) == true) {
        changedNumber += String.valueOf(c);
    } else if (Character.isLetter(c) == true) {
        changedNumber += String.valueOf(decode(c));
    } else {
        System.out.println("Improper input");
    }
```

Right now you are directly assigning digit to `phoneNumber` and you are just calling `decode` but you are not using returned value.

```
phoneNumber = String.valueOf(c);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String temp=""
while (i != phoneNumber.length()) {
        char c = phoneNumber.charAt(i);
        i++;
        if (Character.isDigit(c) == true) {
            temp += String.valueOf(c);
        } else if (Character.isLetter(c) == true) {
            temp += decode(c);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Improper input");
        }
  }
 phoneNumber = temp;
    System.out.println("Numeric version of phone number: " + phoneNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `phoneNumber` is never changed. You can create a new string called `numericPhoneNumber` and manipulate it instead.

And the next issue is this line.

```
phoneNumber = String.valueOf(c);
```

You are assigning the phoneNumber to the single character. You need to append that. A fixed version would be this.

```
String numericPhoneNumber = "";

for (char ch : phoneNumber.toCharArray())
{
    if (Character.isLetter(ch))
        numericPhoneNumber += decode(ch);
    else
        numericPhoneNumber += ch;
}
```

There is no need to check for digit, they will be handled by the else block. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, a couple things. First off, you are not assigning the changes to a new string. Add a temporary string and use += to assign the new changes, or, an even better approach, create a new `StringBuilder` object and append the changes using the `.append()` method:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String phoneNumber;

System.out.print("Enter a phonetic phone number: ");
phoneNumber = input.nextLine();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); //StringBuilder Object

for (int i = 0; i < phoneNumber.length(); i++)
{
    if (Character.isLetter(phoneNumber.charAt(i)))
    {
        sb.append(decode(phoneNumber.charAt(i))); //Nice, easy-to-use append() method, which takes objects of most types
    }
    else if (Character.isDigit(phoneNumber.charAt(i)))
    {
        sb.append(phoneNumber.charAt(i));
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Improper input");
    }
}
System.out.println("Numeric version of phone number: " + sb.toString());
```

Second thing I should mention, your `decode(char c)` function, while well written, should convert the parameter to upper case when you use it, just in case someone enters a lowercase letter:

```
switch (Character.toUpperCase(c))
{
    //case statements
}
```